# ZipArchive downloading empty zip files

Tags: php, download, zip, php-ziparchive

I am attempting to create a zip file that has a simple text file inside. Unfortunatly when I open the zip file, the file is empty, although in the code I have added in a text file.

I have looked for other questions on the topic with no avail and I have tried adding different files such as photos , but the zip is always empty.

How can I succesfully add files to my zip?

Here is the commented code

```php
if($_POST['down']){

  ob_clean(); //clean and flush
  ob_end_flush();
  
  $zip = new ZipArchive(); //create new zip 
  $filename = 'images.zip'; //call the zip a name
  
  if($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) == FALSE){  //if zip can't be opened or created, kill the script
      die('nozip');
  }
  
  
  $string = 'wef2emfofp32fo2mfomepofm'; // a string 
  $zip->addFromString('text.txt', $string); //add the string to the zip
  $zip->close(); //close zip
  

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename(str_replace(' ', '_', $filename)));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

    //download the zip
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove these codes

```
  if($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) == FALSE){  //if zip can't be opened or created, kill the script
  die('nozip');
```

}

and surround everything else with a try catch block. You might find answers in the exception message if that block is not itself the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
With this simple code (from php documentaion)

I have created succesfully the zip and the content

<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```